# How to show Image with UV coordinates?

Tags: uv

I have a Color Grid on my model, but I can't see it in a viewport.

[image]

Comment: You need to set viewport shading to Material Preview or Rendered

Comment: @garyyang Please, next time use more straight forward title, that is more descriptive to your issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

UV texture can be seen also in Solid mode, just enable **Texture Overlay**

[image]